# Why does git rebase require a 3-way merge?

Tags: git, merge, rebase

I'm trying to figure out why rebase requires a three-way merge. For instance, if we have

```
A1 - A2
 \
  B1
```

And I've checked out B1, and I want to perform:

```
git rebase A2
```

why does git merge A2, B1 AND A1? Why wouldn't A2 and B1 suffice? I mean, don't A2 and B1 as commit contain the complete current snapshot of the tree?

Comment: thank you, that is what I was trying to show with my question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To perform a merge, Git needs to find out, what exactly happened in the two branches since the common ancestor (`A1`). As you have said correctly, Git stores snapshots of the commits/trees so to get an actual change set, it has to compare `A2` to `A1` and `B1` to `A1` and then merge those individual change sets.

The same thing happens in a rebase. To apply the change set of `A2` on `B1`, we first need to calculate that change set from the differences between `A1` and `A2`. And then we can apply that to `B1`. You can think of a rebase as something similar to an automated generation of patch files. First it generates all those patch files from the old branch and applies them then to the current HEAD.

So, we need all those three commits to actually calculate the differences, as we cannot figure out what happened in a commit just by looking at that commit.