# What algorithm is used during "git rebase"?

Tags: git

I can't find an explanation of how git does a rebase internally.

The most frequent answer is about applying patches on a base commit but I don't see how it can be true, because there's no way to correctly apply a patch to a (possibly) completely changed file. Three-way merge is mentioned but without saying precisely what is merged.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you dig through the Git code, you will find that there are in fact multiple different internal (or "back end") algorithms used for rebase.  This has evolved over time: Git 2.26 (March 2020) switched the default from an internal program called `git-rebase--am` to `git-rebase--interactive`, and Git 2.12 (Feb 2017) switched the interactive variant from using a shell script to using what Git calls its *sequencer*.  So there's no single right answer that applies to every invocation of `git rebase` or in every version of Git.  Note that even in very old versions of Git, `git rebase -i` uses the `git-rebase--interactive` back end.

In any case, think of this as having each commit copied *as if* by `git cherry-pick`, or *as if* by `git format-patch` and `git am`.  There are some minor differences for the older `git am`-based algorithm—for instance, it doesn't handle file renames at all; that's the main reason it was retired—and in the case of modern Git we mostly use `git cherry-pick` anyway, but it may be easier to *think about* this as "getting and applying a patch".

The more interesting thing, then, is really how `git am` and/or `git cherry-pick` do their jobs.  The long answer is long and boring and probably best shortened to "go look at the source code", but the short answer is: `git am` *tries* to apply the change as a patch first, and only if that fails, falls back on a full three-way merge.  See the `-3` flag in `git am` for a brief description as well.  Meanwhile `git cherry-pick` just does a straight three-way merge.

The merge base used here is often not all that helpful.  Consider this initial DAGlet and a `git rebase` that intends to copy `A` to `A'` and `B` to `B'`, appending these atop commit `D`:

```
       A--B        <-- branch
      /
...--*------C--D   <-- origin/branch
```

The *first* cherry pick op is picking `A`, so it diffs commit `A` against commit `*` (the merge base of the two branches).  With the `git am` method, Git tries to apply this as a patch atop `D`.  If that fails, or if you're using interactive rebase resulting in `git cherry-pick`, the commit (if cherry-pick) or each failed file (if `git am`-ing)—get run through the three-way merge process.

That's actually pretty reasonable: we're really trying to replay `*`-to-`A` after dealing with `*`-to-`D`.  The final result is `A'`:

```
       A--B        <-- branch
      /
...--*------C--D   <-- origin/branch
                \
                 A'    [detached HEAD]
```

But now we copy `B`, which for `git am` means producing a patch going from `A` to `B`.  For those parts of the patch that apply, we just apply them.  For files where there is a conflict, this time we diff files from `A`-vs-`B` and `A`-vs-`A'`, doing low-level file merges for each failed-to-patch file using these diffs.  `A` is kind of a weird merge base here, but it's clearly better than nothing, and it usually works perfectly.

For actual `git cherry-pick` rebases, Git uses the entire commit `A` as the merge base and does a normal three-way merge across the entire tree.  Each file's merge base is the version of the file from commit `A`.

(If we had more commits past `B`, this would continue for the rest of them.)

It's easy to see that this *must* be the case for the non-interactive:

```
git format-patch -k --stdout --full-index --cherry-pick --right-only \
    --src-prefix=a/ --dst-prefix=b/ --no-renames --no-cover-letter \
    "$revisions" ${restrict_revision+^$restrict_revision} \
    >"$GIT_DIR/rebased-patches"
...
git am $git_am_opt --rebasing --resolvemsg="$resolvemsg" \
    ${gpg_sign_opt:+"$gpg_sign_opt"} <"$GIT_DIR/rebased-patches"
```

code, since `git am` gets only the `Index:` lines to use to construct base files.  It's trickier to locate in the `git rebase` code, as the critical bits are buried deep in [sequencer.c](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/sequencer.c).  In older Git, you could just look at the shell script and see how it ran `git cherry-pick`.

Comment: Wow, what a thorough answer.     Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks @torek! Why do you say that "`git cherry-pick` just does a straight three-way merge"? The doc says it applies changes. I though it did so by first applying a diff `<remote-commit>^..<remote-commit>`.

Comment: @RomainPellerin: If you dig into the source code, you will find that `git cherry-pick` invokes the sequencer, and the sequencer picks the appropriate parent as the merge base and then [runs either `do_recursive_merge` or `try_merge_command` as appropriate](https://github.com/git/git/blob/e3331758f12da22f4103eec7efe1b5304a9be5e9/sequencer.c#L1772-L1796). The documentation explanation is a white lie that's intended to be more understandable.

Comment: @RomainPellerin: note that this is different from `git rebase`, which may (depending on arguments) invoke `git format-patch` and `git am`. The `git am` step can apply a patch without going through a three-way merge *if* the patch applies cleanly. Otherwise it *does* go through a three-way merge thanks to using `--3way` and the index lines (generated with `--full-index`).

Comment: @torek thank your for the explanation. Funny to see that at some point `cherry-pick` did [apply a simple diff](https://github.com/git/git/blob/045f82cbee3135a3d75256828b0cf101eedf38c8/git-revert-script#L15). I wonder what motivated the change to a three-way merge.

Comment: Looks like I found the [culprit](https://github.com/git/git/commit/acb4441e0dabaaa666ecae11fdafc27c3691e763#diff-832427bf50111f6782c8d1778946d6ad). `cherry-pick` apparently uses a 3-way merge to notice renames.

Comment: @RomainPellerin: Just so: without a merge base it's impossible to identify "same" files across the three points of the merge. (It also handles some conflicting-change cases better.)

Comment: @torek what do you mean? My question was about the motives to use a 3-way merge instead of applying a simple diff. I understand that a 3-way merge requires a merge base.

Comment: @RomainPellerin: I mean the same thing you do: you can't find renames (i.e., identify that file foo in revision B is "the same file" as file bar in revision L and file baz in revision R). In other words, the identity of a file is not necessarily its *name*, it may be some other quality that determines whether two files are "the same" file.

Comment: Good, thank you once again @torek for your explanation. Greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

> The most frequent answer is about applying patches on a base commit but it cannot be true. There's no way to correctly apply a patch to a (possibly) completely changed file.

It *is* true - `rebase` is essentially doing `cherry-pick` plus some other bookkeeping.

But your second sentence is also correct - if the file has completely changed, you'll likely encounter a conflict when you try to rebase.

Comment: So where is this three-way merge happening? I'm not talking about a conflict situation but about an auto merge rather. Old Git rebase message was saying:  Using index info to reconstruct a base tree...
A   ch10.asciidoc
Falling back to patching base and 3-way merge...  How should I understand this?

Comment: @listerreg: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8513084/why-does-git-rebase-require-a-3-way-merge.  Each patch is automatically generated from a pair of sequential commits, and then applied to a 3rd commit.  Thus "three-way".